# Input parser: one parameter dependent from another parameter

Tags: matlab

I am using the input parser functionality a lot but now I am facing the following issue:

I am coding an object that computes the rate-of-change of time series, i.e. one input argument is a matrix of doubles (`timeSeries`). A second input parameter is the time period used to compute the rate-of-change (`lag`). `lag` can be a vector wherby different rate-of-changes will be computed. A third input vector is called `weightVector`. `weightVector` will be used to compute an average of all rate-of-changes and applies the appropriate weights to the respective rate-of-change results.

Now, I always like to define some default values when using input parser. I would like to define `weightVector` to be an equal weighted vector. However, the length of the default `weightVector` is dependent on the length of `lag`. For example, if `lag = [1,2,3]`, then `weightVector`should equal `[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]`. How am I supposed to code a situation like this? My current code for the constructor looks like this:

```
function obj = roc(timeSeries, varargin)
    %% Input parser

    % 1. Create input parser instance
    p = inputParser;

    % 2. Default values for input arguments
    default_lag = 1;
    default_weightVector = 1/length(lag); % This line is causing
                                          % problems as LAG isn't
                                          % defined, yet.

    % 3. Validation of input arguments
    valid_lag = {'vector', 'nonempty', 'integer', 'positive'};
    check_lag = @(x) validateattributes(x, {'numeric'}, valid_lag);
    valid_weightVector = {'vector', 'nonempty'};
    check_weightVector = @(x) validateattributes(x, {'numeric'}, ...
        valid_weightVector);

    % 4. Add input arguments to input scheme
    p.addRequired('timeSeries');
    p.addParamater('lag', default_lag, check_lag);
    p.addParameter('weightVector', default_weightVector, check_weightVector);

    % 5. Parse input arguments
    parse(p, timeSeries, varargin{:});

    % 6. Assign results to variables
    lag = p.Results.lag;
    weightVector = p.Results.weightVector;


    %% Main code

end % Constructor
```

Comment: Set the default to a value it can never be (e.g. `NaN` or `''`) and have a conditional after `parse` that checks to see if `weightVector` needs to be generated from the validated `lag` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
function obj = roc(timeSeries, varargin)
    %% Input parser

    % 1. Create input parser instance
    p = inputParser;

    % 2. Default values for input arguments
    default_lag = 1;
    default_weightVector = 1;

    % 3. Validation of input arguments
    valid_lag = {'vector', 'nonempty', 'integer', 'positive'};
    check_lag = @(x) validateattributes(x, {'numeric'}, valid_lag);

    % 4. Add input arguments to input scheme
    p.addRequired('timeSeries');
    p.addParameter('lag', default_lag, check_lag);
    p.addParameter('weightVector', default_weightVector);

    % 5. Parse input arguments
    parse(p, timeSeries, varargin{:});

    % 6. Assign results to variables
    lag = p.Results.lag;

    if check_weightVector(p.Results.weightVector, lag) == true
        weightVector = p.Results.weightVector;
    end

    function vout = check_weightVector(weightVector, lag) % validation function
        if length(lag) ~= length(weightVector)
            error('lengthWeightVector:WrongNumberOfElements', 'The number of elements in "weightVector" must correspond to the number of elements in "lag"');
        elseif sum(weightVector) ~= 1
            error('sumWeightVector:SumNotEqualToOne', 'The sum of elements in "weightVector" must equal 1');
        end

        vout = true;
    end


    %% Main code
end
```